Micronaut @Error is not catching HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
I'm working on a way to handle errors that should show an error page in HTML format. But it's not working, and instead of showing the error page, it's giving back a default JSON message saying {"message": "Internal Server Error"}.
Here is my controller:


@Controller("/mail")
class MailController {

    @View("mail")
    @Get("/")
    fun index: Map<String, Any?>{
        val res = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        
        // throw Exception("This is a test exception")

        return res
    }
}



The error handler:


 
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus

@Controller("/err")
class ErrorController {
    @View("500")
    @Error(status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, global = true)
    fun errorHandler(e: Exception): Map<String, Any> {
        return HashMap()
    }
}



